# Importing time and heart rate data into SQL Server from TCX file via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I'm attempting to import a tcx file from Garmin connect into SQL Server with SSIS. Unfortunately, I'm at a complete loss as to how I would create an xsd in order to import the datapoints I want. The Garmin XSD is http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd. And the parts I'm concerned about are only the elements here:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Trackpoint_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:dateTime" name="Time"/>
        <xsd:element type="Position_t" name="Position" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:double" name="AltitudeMeters" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:double" name="DistanceMeters" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t" name="HeartRateBpm" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="CadenceValue_t" name="Cadence" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="SensorState_t" name="SensorState" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element type="Extensions_t" name="Extensions" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
```

Any pointers on how to create the xsd would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to import part of XML file without modifications, you do not have to design your own xsd. All you need to do is:

- Take XSD file from Garmit (presuming it is valid and aligns with your data) and your XML file
- In SSIS package, add dataflow task, XML source in it, select your XML file as source and Garmin XSD file as schema file
- Alternatively, you can try this, XML Source can design (guess) XSD from XML provided. I would recommend this only as a starting point, since guessed XSD is very approximate and based only on the sample provided; it can misinterpret node and attribute types based on the sample.
- XML Source usually produce multitude of outputs, so you have to check with data viewer which one contains data you need.

After playing with this prototype, you can transform package to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the XSD from Garmin doesn't work.  It errors out on a few nodes that don't have any output.  I'm marking yours as the answer due to it would work if the XSD was valid.

Comment: @DaytonBrown, thank you! If Garmin's XSD is wrong and you do not feel creating it yourself, you can stack several XML samples and generate XSDs for them from SSIS editor and XML source as pointed out in point 3 above.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide your XML-file... But I found one [sample of a TCX-file here](https://github.com/mlt/schwinn810/wiki/Sample-.TCX-Files) and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28531500/5089204). Reading this does not need a schema. I hope, that you can solve your problems, when you see the following example:

```
    DECLARE @xml XML=
    N'<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Running">
      <Id>2015-01-25T12:14:34Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2015-01-25T12:14:34Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>507.0989990</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>1000.0000000</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>2.5790000</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>95</Calories>
        <AverageHeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
          <Value>155</Value>
        </AverageHeartRateBpm>
        <MaximumHeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
          <Value>173</Value>
        </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
        <Intensity>Resting</Intensity>
        <TriggerMethod>Distance</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2015-01-25T12:14:34Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>50.8918607</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>16.7403161</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>233.1999969</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>0.0000000</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>88</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Extensions>
              <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" CadenceSensor="Footpod">
                <Speed>0.0000000</Speed>
              </TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
        </Track>
        <Track />
        <Extensions>
          <FatCalories xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/FatCalories/v1">
            <Value>0</Value>
          </FatCalories>
          <LX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
            <AvgSpeed>1.9720000</AvgSpeed>
          </LX>
        </Extensions>
      </Lap>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2')
select Act.value(N'@Sport','nvarchar(max)') AS Activity_Sport
      ,Act.value(N'(Id)[1]','datetime') AS Activity_Id
      ,Lap.value(N'@StartTime','datetime') AS Lap_StartTime
      ,Lap.value(N'(TotalTimeSeconds)[1]','decimal(20,8)') AS Lap_TotalTimeSeconds
      --more fields
      ,Lap.value(N'(Calories)[1]','int') AS Lap_TotalTimeSeconds
      ,Lap.value(N'(AverageHeartRateBpm/Value)[1]','int') AS Lap_AverageHeartRateBpm
      ,Lap.value(N'(MaximumHeartRateBpm/Value)[1]','int') AS Lap_MaximumHeartRateBpm
      ,Lap.value(N'(Intensity)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Lap_Intensity
      --more fields
      ,TrP.value(N'(Time)[1]','datetime') AS Track_Trackpoint_Time
      ,TrP.value(N'(Position/LatitudeDegrees)[1]','decimal(20,8)') AS Track_Trackpoint_Position_LatitudeDegrees
      --more fields
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/TrainingCenterDatabase/Activities/Activity') AS A(Act)
OUTER APPLY Act.nodes(N'Lap') AS B(Lap)
OUTER APPLY Lap.nodes(N'Track/Trackpoint') AS C(TrP)
```

The result

```
Activity_Sport  Activity_Id             Lap_StartTime           Lap_TotalTimeSeconds    ....
Running         2015-01-25 12:14:34.000 2015-01-25 12:14:34.000 507.09899900            ....
```

Comment: I need to use SSIS with this.  Which means that I need the XML import.  This is straight SQL.  Which would work if I was using bulkcopy or something similar.  Thanks for the example though.